# g++ linking local libraries

Tags: c++, linker, g++

New to C++ and somewhat new to compiled languages in general. I've been passed a university specific code library for a class for use in completing my assignments. However, I cannot figure out how to properly link it. Directories are laid out as follows:

```
Assignment
    lib
       UniversityCPPLib
          .cpp and .h files
    res
    src
       .cpp for my assignment
```

Just calling

```
    g++ -o assignment.cpp assignment
```

gives me

```
    No such file or directory
```

and I am not sure how to use -L to specify the local library.

*EDIT: Also, relatively new to SO in general. Would someone mind telling me why I keep getting downvotes? I am still learning here and will gladly correct myself if I am breaking any of the rules here.

Comment: please provide the complete error message

Comment: assignment.cpp:14:21: fatal error: console.h: No such file or directory (console.h is in the university library)

Comment: Use `-I` (uppercase i) to indicate where the compiler should look for header files, `-L` for libraries, and `-lname` (lowercase L) to link with `libname.a`.

Comment: Please take at least a quick look at the documentation for your compiler before asking... Your -o is also going to have fun effects (like your dog eating your assignment).

Comment: Whoops. Assuming syntax was the same as gcc was a bad idea. Thanks. Still have the same problem though.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Was not aware of that thank you. Just looked through the docs. It seems that g++ assignment.c++ -I/path/through/filesystem/lib should be enough? I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Should be good enough, yes.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Got it, with a slight silly modification. g++ assignment.cpp -I/path/through/filesystem/lib/UniversityCPPLib. At least I think it works (many errors within the library, but that's another issue entirely). Mind adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

To - L option give the complete path until lib directory .  Then use - l option with the name of library without suffix.

Comment: As from the comments OP misses a `-I` option rather than `-L`.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. g++ assignment.cpp -L/path/through/filesystem/lib -lUniversityCPPLib ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MatsPetersson and @πάνταῥεῖ. The required option is -I, not -L. Synax as follows:

```
    g++ assignment.cpp -I/path/through/filesystem/lib/UniversityCPPLib
```